# No notification for comment, when some characters like '-' are appended to @username by a commentator.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, notifications, global-inbox

[The comment in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626279/running-time-of-insertion-into-2-hashtables-with-iteration-and-printing#comment29137246_19626313).

For easy reference, the comment was `@Dukeling- I ...` on someone else' post.
The comment wasn't edited.

This comment does not appear in my inbox or under [my responses](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1711796/dukeling?tab=responses).

I posted 2 comments and deleted one before that was posted (or was it 3 and 2), might that have something to do with it?

Might the `-` have something to do with it?
Doesn't this classify as ["Single trailing punctuation" (point 12)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/206447)? If not, shouldn't it?

Comment: To be fair, nothing in point 12 says hyphens are considered as trailing punctuation (only periods, commas and colons are mentioned).

Comment: it's the `-`'s fault

Comment: @mehow I knew the hyphen site would find a way to annoy us somehow...

Answer (score 4):

The hyphen is explicitly a matchable character when processing comment replies. And indeed, it is used in many names. As examples (the top 10 by reputation on stackoverflow):

```
Id          DisplayName
----------- ----------------------------------------
20862       Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams
34509       Johannes Schaub - litb
9951        e-satis
36565       David Rodríguez - dribeas
13          Chris Jester-Young
4725        Tom Hawtin - tackline
659804      Ernest Friedman-Hill
464581      Cheers and hth. - Alf
95382       Michael Krelin - hacker
927034      K-ballo
```

As such, as far as the system is concerned, that was not a match - the same as if they'd commented with `@Dukelingabcdef` or `@Dukeblah`.

Comment: ["Though a dot is valid in a username, the last dot is removed for matching"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/206447) - shouldn't we do something similar with all valid punctuation marks? Can I add a feature request for this or change this to a feature request?

Comment: @Dukeling most punctuation marks are already not valid in matching - it is mainly `.` and `-` that would be affected here (no `,`, `:`, `;`, `?`, `!` etc). And ending the mention with `@foo-` is a *tiny tiny* edge case. The reason it is supported for `.` is for (and this is directly from comments in the code): `remove a trailing period to handle comments like "Thanks @Martin. That really helped."`. In the case of `-`, it feels like "the user made a typo and got your name wrong" is a more genuine cause of a missed mention... thoughts?

Comment: Thoughts- The comment in question is an exact example of what might happen. Normally it's "Thoughts: ..." or "Thoughts - ...", but the "Thoughts- ..." variation isn't that different.  I tried writing [a query](http://data.stackexchange.com/) to see how often this happens, but, after writing a basic function, saw that I don't have access to create regular / temporary functions.